# How to show rows-records between two tab form?

Tags: forms, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, records

In my Form, I have Two TabPages, with the same `DataSource` for each.

In `TabPageA` I have all records from my `DataSource`. I select records in `TabPageA` and I want to only show, in `TabPageB`, those records I selected previously in `TabPageA`.

If I don't select anything in `TabPageA` I don't see anything in `TabPageB`

[image: My form body]

For example if in my GridA I selected Record#4 , in GridB I see only Record#4.

Comment: Anything you have tried so far`

Comment: Anything you have tried so far?

Comment: I changed in PropertiesTabPageB the ParentPage.
I set the TabPageA, but nothin result, I see all records in TabPageB.

Comment: This is hard to answer without seeing the form and the tab pages. Maybe you could link some screenshots? Or can you describe a bit more detailed what the two tab pages are showing? For example, are both tabs using grids?
Also I think the last word in your second sentence should be `TabPageA`, not `TabPageB`.

Comment: Hi FH-Inway, I putted my Form body.
In GridA I selected records , and in GridB I only show the records selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to filter `TabPageB` differently from `TabPageA` easily due to the fact they share the same DataSource.

There are two quick ways to modify this.

**Keep it as one DataSource**: 
Create a global `QueryBuildRange` to easily update the range on selected records.

```
public class FormRun extends ObjectRun

    {
        QueryBuildRange qbr;
    }
```

Override the `init` of your datasource. Here you will set the qbr:

```
public void init()
{
    super();
    qbr = this.queryBuildDataSource().addRange(fieldNum(SalesTable, RecId));
}
```

Then override the `pageActivated` `TabPage` method for each to set the range and re-execute the query to your liking:

`TabPageA`:

```
public void pageActivated()
{
    super();

    qbr.value('');

    SalesTable_ds.executeQuery();
}
```

`TabPageB`

```
public void pageActivated()
{
    super();

    element.createRange();

    SalesTable_ds.executeQuery();
}
```

Method to update range:

```
public void createRange()
{
    MultiSelectionHelper    multiSelectionHelper = MultiSelectionHelper::createFromCaller(this);
    common                  common;
    Set                     set = new Set(Types::Int64);

    // Necessary if the datasource you want is not the header datasource.
    multiSelectionHelper.parmDatasource(SalesTable_ds);

    common = multiSelectionHelper.getFirst();

    while (common)
    {
        // Use of set not necessary, but a little cleaner.
        set.add(common.RecId);

        common = MultiSelectionHelper.getNext();
    }

    qbr.value(strRem(set.toString(), '"{}'));
}
```

This is somewhat dirty, but you get the idea and could clean it up as needed.

**Two Datasources:** 
Update the range on the second datasource (used by `TabPageB`) based on the multi-selection of the first datasource. But I'm assuming you only want one datasource for some reason.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for your help.
I tried your advice, but in my GridB I see all records from my DataSource.

Comment: I would want to display only the information of the selected records in GridA (TabPageA)

Comment: For example if in my GridA I selected Record#4 , in GridB I see only Record#4.


                    You can see in GridA I have some fields, in GridB I have other different fields (from same record).
Thanks for you care!

Comment: That is effectively what this does. When you switch tab pages, it forces the datasource to update a query build range to only the selected first in the first grid. It won't matter the fields are different as long as it is the same datasource. A slightly simpler option I presented is to have two separate datasources and only have a range on the one used for grid b.